# How to get the selected values in a multiple select Dropdown component in the onClose event?

Tags: semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

Have a look at this sandbox, the object doesn't seem to have the value defined onClose.
[Forked codesandbox:](https://codesandbox.io/s/wqqyrv5xjl)
https://codesandbox.io/s/wqqyrv5xjl

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert, but I do have an app that is using a Semantic UI React dropdown with multiple selections just like you are. I don't rely on `onClose`, but instead keep track of selection state using `onChange`. Every time I get a change, I update state with the new selections. In my case I update my Redux state, but if you prefer, you can keep it in React component state.